# Printing a content of a file to the screen in perl

Tags: perl, file

I Have a perl script which write a few lines into file. (I checked and see that the file is written correctly)
right after that I want to print the content to the screen, the way I'm trying to do it- is to read the file and print it

```
open (FILE, '>', "tmpLogFile.txt") or die "could not open the log file\n";
$aaa = <FILE>; 
close (FILE);  
print $aaa;
```

but I get nothing on the screen, what do I do wrong?

Comment: Is this the actual code? As-is, you're opening the file for writing, then attempting to read from it (`$aaa = <FILE>;`). I wouldn't expect `$aaa` to have anything in it, but neither would I expect any file contents.

Comment: `perl -pe0 tmpLogFile.txt`

Answer (score 7):

To **read** you need to specify the open mode as `<`.
Also, `$aaa = <FILE>` has scalar context, and only reads a line.
Using `print <FILE>` you can have list context and read all lines:

```
open (FILE, '<', "tmpLogFile.txt") or die "could not open the log file\n";
print <FILE>;
close (FILE);
```

Comment: thanks, now I understood my mistake . but' it's still not working

Comment: It does work here. What do you mean by "not working"? Did you use my code exactly as shown or with modifications? Is the tmpLogFile.txt actually there and contains the lines you expect?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = 'data.txt';
open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename)
  or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";

while (my $row = <$fh>) {
    chomp $row;
    print "$row\n";
  }
print "done\n"
```